# Allow iphone to sleep while updating ui

Tags: iphone, objective-c, sleep

I am writing a music player that I am trying to allow to go to sleep mode. The problem is, every second, the ui is updated and I think that is preventing the phone from sleep. I added this line:

```
[UIApplication sharedApplication].idleTimerDisabled = NO;
```

and it did nothing. I have seen other apps that go to sleep mode even if the ui is being updated. How can I accomplish this?

Comment: You don't have your screen timeout set high in your settings do you? It can be different for every device... default is 60 sec I believe. AFAIK updating the UI should not prevent your app from going to sleep.

Comment: I checked my settings and they are set to timeout at one minute. I've had my app running for about 13min now and it still won't go to sleep.

Comment: Interesting. No erroneous settings in your info.plist file or something? Good luck.

Comment: Have you tried rebooting your phone to make sure it isn't something not related to your app? Or tested on another device? Seems like an odd issue to have.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based on the comments, Are you running your app while attached to `Xcode`? By default `Xcode` stops the device going to sleep. If so, just disconnect and run, it should go to sleep (provided your devices sleep timer is not too much)